# How to return the probability of each classified instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Let's say that I already fitted [scikit's SGDC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#sgd), from the documentation I read that `predict_proba()` function return a vector of probability estimates, Thus I did the follwing:

```
In:
proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)

print('proba:',proba.shape)
print(type(prediction))

Out:
proba: (292683, 39)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

However, I do not understand why `proba` has that dimention
 (`292683, 39`), insted of `(292683,)`. **So, my question is how should I return the probability for each classified instance?.** For example a vector full of the probabilities for each classified insance:

```
.9098
.6789
.2346
.4545
...
.9076
```

**Update**

This is my actual output:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38
1.6032895251736538e-09,0.0027001605689774967,1.3127275209812045e-05,0.0004133169272159469,6.421335538574734e-05,0.01244940641130727,4.971270475822253e-05,0.06927362982555345,0.05447770875726582,0.0002585581503775057,1.30512865257421e-05,0.00015347845576367026,0.004231831363568738,0.003134713706992086,0.00017618959500039568,0.004525087952898131,0.07230938415776024,0.004255936398577753,0.0006231217282368267,0.07381737590135892,1.7062740932146373e-05,0.04873946029933614,2.2579270275470988e-05,0.04738213671381574,0.011041250070307537,0.06786077438113797,0.008012001696580576,0.0009697583063038865,0.002640793732663328,0.00041955324710243576,0.005333452308762462,0.0023973060671898918,0.24386456744298726,1.2930500605063882e-05,0.010271860113445061,0.10478318644646997,0.1096803752152842,0.029709960729470408,0.0039009845913073
...
2.70775531177066e-05,0.056826721550724914,0.00021452452508401623,0.005773421211249144,0.03601322253697087,0.03387846954273534,0.0002233544773721261,0.0009621520077239175,0.005573279378280768,0.0011059321386392307,0.00014906386779747047,0.0007207742574711379,0.018149812871977058,0.017479374046348212,0.0004917497325634417,0.009446560753589354,0.37652447022205116,0.008895752894288417,0.00136242543496297,0.1961349850670937,0.011158949542858676,0.0010422870520728268,4.0487954942671204e-05,0.013908461124574075,0.005521009748034979,0.019087261334748272,0.00355886145992077,0.0054657023293853595,0.004395464092632666,0.00018729724505224616,0.0015209690844465442,0.003930224604070839,0.03922346296961368,2.1100171629256666e-05,0.001026959174556334,0.09177893762051553,0.021131552685297615,0.0007056741594152797,0.006342213576191516
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict_proba` returns a vector of form P(y=y_i|x) for each y_i (class). Consequently, you can extract many measures from it. For example, if you are asking "how probable is my model's current classification" (thus your model's certainty in its own prediction) all you have to do is to index this array row-wise with your predictions so you get P(y=pred(x)|x), which is more or less:

```
for probs, pred in zip(clf.predict_proba(x), clf.predict(x)):
  print probs[pred]
```

you might also ask for probability of the correct class (meaning "according to my model, what is the probability of belonging to a valid class") analogously by (I am assuming y holds indexes of valid classes)

```
for probs, truth in zip(clf.predict_proba(x), y):
  print probs[truth]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess 39 is the number of different classes a sample could belong to.As you have done predict_proba. Its going to give you a probability of belonging to each particular class.

**There is never going to be a single probability associated with each sample.**

So, the error metric generally used for such situations is  multi class log loss.

Comment: Thanks for the help... in addition I do not understand my output. I updated my question with details, could you provide an explanation of my output?

Comment: I see.. Could you provide an example of how to use logloss for this situation?... I checked out the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html). Nevertheless it is not very clear.

Comment: So consider each of them, lets start with the first value 1.6e-09. So that is probability of first sample belonging to class 1. 
0.0027 is the probability of first sample belonging to class 2.
and so on.....
So its not hard classification, where it tells you it belongs to one class.
It is soft classification.

Comment: Now I understand... So how should I get the probability of the actual class?, the one that actually it is?. Shall I need to use log_loss?

Comment: Yes you will need to use log loss as your error metric.
https://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow/forums/t/2499/multiclass-logarithmic-loss

The above could prove useful for theoretical understanding.
There was a great post on kaggle about it, but they removed it.

Comment: I am not sure , but you could use this.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html

Comment: Finally, `>>> log_loss(["spam", "ham", "ham", "spam"],  
...          [[.1, .9], [.9, .1], [.8, .2], [.35, .65]])
0.21616...` will return a single probability or a vector full of probabilities?.

Comment: it will return the loss. So, an estimate of how wrong your classification is.
Lesser the loss, better it is.
A loss of 2.0 is generally seen if you say on each sample, that it is equally likely to be in each class.
So if there are 39 classes(in your instance), then 1/39,1/39 and so on.
I hope your classification will be better :p